# Перебор объектов json

Tags: javascript, json

Есть json файл с такой структурой:

```
{"firstweek": [
        {
            "day": "понеділок",
            "pair": "3",
            "start": "12:05",
            "end": "13:25",
            "subject": "Л Моделювання та аналіз ПрЗаб  В",
            "room": "Б-505",
            "group": "вся",
            "teacher": "***"
        }],
"secondweek": [
        {
            "day": "понеділок",
            "pair": "1",
            "start": "8:20",
            "end": "9:40",
            "subject": "Лб2 Штучний інтелект",
            "room": "Б-523   ",
            "group": "підгрупа",
            "teacher": "***"
        }    ]
}
```

Есть ли способ перебрать данный файл по значениям firstweek, secondweek?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/rNOeYxG

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/NWqMZrN

Answer (score 1):

Конечно можно с помощью `JSON.parse`. Если есть отдельный файл, то сначала читаем его с помощью [модуля fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) (сразу поясню: в браузере данный код не сработает), а потом уже парсим его и работаем с ним, как с обычным объектом в js.

```
const fs = require('fs'); // подключаем модуль для работы с файловой структурой

const dataFromFile = fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf-8'); // читаем файл
const dataToJson = JSON.parse(dataFromFile); // парсим в объект

console.log(dataToJson.firstweek); // первый массив firstweek

for (const key in dataToJson) {
  console.log(key); // выводит ключи в объекте
}
```